# Alternative for .include Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I have a string `let x: string = "abCDFg"`, And I wanna check whether one value is present in the string or not. So i tried `x.includes('a')`. I realized that .includes not supporting in IE. Is there any alternative for .include? Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `indexOf`:

```
x.indexOf('a') > -1
```

See also [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Or you could use Polyfills from for example [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) and use all the syntactic sugar even in IE.

Comment: Yeah good suggestion.. But what if my string is a word like "thisismyword" and i wanna check whether the string contains the word "word"?

Comment: You so `"thisismyword".indexOf("word") > -1`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex.

```
/a/.test(x);
```

Note if you want to test from a certain index, you'll have to adjust the regex accordingly.